# How to add path to cookies using redux middlewares?

Tags: cookies, redux, redux-middleware

I am using `redux-cookies-middleware` and there I can pass just `name` and `value` for the cookies. But if I need to add `path` how should I pass it?

`{
  session: {
    name: 'session'  // name of the cookie in which the value of session will be synced
  },
  'auth.token': {
    name: 'auth_token'  // name of the cookie in which the value of auth.token will be synced
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `setCookie` option when initializing your middleware. This is a placeholder for a function to be called when setting cookies. Once you have a custom function for setting cookies you will have more control over things like path, domain, expiry, etc..

Comment: Thank you for help!